# Chess font specific problems on a linux arch based distribution (arcolinux)

Tags: fonts, chess, chessboard, installing-fonts, chessfss

For short, it is about getting (white and) black figurine fonts to work, so that typing some chess pages would focus on chess, not on the latex clutter around them. Explicitly:

**Question: The Berlin chess font is not working. Which may be the problem on my machine, and how to solve the problem?**

I will first state the problem, trying to isolate it in a relatively minimal sample case,
but also try to show the direction of usage.
My problem is a joined problem having three sides

- latex is one component, so this is the reason for being on this stackexchange domain,
- the linux distribution, which is arcolinux, based on arch and using for latex purposes the standard texlive packages, together with my picked and added AUR repositories, so it may address also other user,
- the installation on my machine, yes, this may be also the reason, so i have to explain what happens in this tunnel.

I am asking here rather than on an arch site, since i feel it is rather a latex problem (possibly only on my machine).

---

The latex installation contains the following packages:

```
[dan@k9 ~]$ pacman -Ss texlive | grep -F installed
extra/texlive-basic 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-bibtexextra 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-bin 2024.0-1 [installed]
extra/texlive-binextra 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-context 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-fontsextra 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-fontsrecommended 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-fontutils 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-formatsextra 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-games 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-humanities 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-langeuropean 2024.0-3 (texlive-lang) [installed]
extra/texlive-langgerman 2024.0-3 (texlive-lang) [installed]
extra/texlive-latex 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-latexextra 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-latexrecommended 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-luatex 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-mathscience 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-meta 2024.0-3 [installed]
extra/texlive-metapost 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-music 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-pictures 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-plaingeneric 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-pstricks 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-publishers 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
extra/texlive-xetex 2024.0-3 (texlive) [installed]
```

There is no arch official `texlive-full` package. (The one in AUR would install under `\opt`, it is definitively not what i want.) Inside AUR there is a package that seems useful for my purposes:

```
[dan@k9 ~]$ yay -Ss chess-merida
aur/chess-merida-unicode 1.1-1 (+2 0.02) (Out-of-date: 2024-01-22) 
    A truetype chess font for diagrams and figurine notation
aur/chess-merida 1.1-2 (+6 0.00) (Installed)
    A truetype chess font for diagrams and figurine notation
```

The corresponding aur information is on https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/chess-merida.

---

The following code tries to (also) get the black queen figurine, and work with it in a natural manner. For instance, we are in the middle of a long story about the Najdorf, and want to explain where the pieces belong in a simple manner. It may feel simpler to build a sentence like "♛c7 is a main attacker..." than "The black ♕c7 is a main attacker ..." so the easy access to the black figurines gives some freedom for a book writer.

**The part with red comments is the problem.**

---

*Sample code:*

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{chessfss,chessboard,xskak,texmate}
% \pdfmapfile{=chess-enpassant.map}
% \usetextfig
\usesymfig
\setchessfontfamily{berlin}

\newcommand\p{{\raisebox{-0.33ex}\BlackPawnOnWhite}}
\newcommand\n{{\raisebox{-0.33ex}\BlackKnightOnWhite}}
\renewcommand\b{{\raisebox{-0.33ex}\BlackBishopOnWhite}}
\renewcommand\r{{\raisebox{-0.33ex}\BlackRookOnWhite}}
\newcommand\q{{\raisebox{-0.33ex}\BlackQueenOnWhite}}
\renewcommand\k{{\raisebox{-0.33ex}\BlackKnightOnWhite}}

\renewcommand\P{\pawn}
\newcommand\N{\knight}
\newcommand\B{\bishop}
\newcommand\R{\rook}
\newcommand\Q{\queen}
\newcommand\K{\king}

\parindent0pt
\advance\textwidth by 4cm
\advance\oddsidemargin by -2cm
\begin{document}
\sf\small
White pieces: \P\N\B\R\Q\K
using \verb:\pawn\knight\bishop\rook\queen\king:

Black pieces: \p\n\b\r\q\k
using \verb:\BlackPawnOnWhite\BlackKnightOnWhite: and so on.

\bigskip

White pieces using \verb+\textsymfigsymbol+
-- {\color{red}not the right Berlin font}:

\verb+\textsymfigsymbol{p}+ \textsymfigsymbol{p}\par
\verb+\textsymfigsymbol{n}+ \textsymfigsymbol{n}\par
\verb+\textsymfigsymbol{b}+ \textsymfigsymbol{b}\par
\verb+\textsymfigsymbol{r}+ \textsymfigsymbol{r}\par
\verb+\textsymfigsymbol{q}+ \textsymfigsymbol{q}\par
\verb+\textsymfigsymbol{k}+ \textsymfigsymbol{k}\par

Black pieces using \verb+\textsymfigsymbol+
-- {\color{red}not the right Berlin font, thus also bad fontshape}:

\verb+{\fontshape{bl}\selectfont \textsymfigsymbol{p}}+ {\fontshape{bl}\selectfont \textsymfigsymbol{p}}\par
\verb+{\fontshape{bl}\selectfont \textsymfigsymbol{n}}+ {\fontshape{bl}\selectfont \textsymfigsymbol{n}}\par
\verb+{\fontshape{bl}\selectfont \textsymfigsymbol{b}}+ {\fontshape{bl}\selectfont \textsymfigsymbol{b}}\par
\verb+{\fontshape{bl}\selectfont \textsymfigsymbol{r}}+ {\fontshape{bl}\selectfont \textsymfigsymbol{r}}\par
\verb+{\fontshape{bl}\selectfont \textsymfigsymbol{q}}+ {\fontshape{bl}\selectfont \textsymfigsymbol{q}}\par
\verb+{\fontshape{bl}\selectfont \textsymfigsymbol{k}}+ {\fontshape{bl}\selectfont \textsymfigsymbol{k}}\par

\bigskip

White queen moves to c4 with \verb+\wmove+: \wmove{Qc4}

Black queen moves to c5 with \verb+\bmove+: \bmove{Qc5}

\begin{center}
Diagram XXX
\\
\chessboard[
setfen=r1b1k2r/2qnbppp/p2pp3/1p4P1/3NPP2/2N2Q2/PPP4P/2KR1B1R w kq - 1 13
, moveid=13w]
\\
% Position after |Nf6-d7|, white exchanged |Bg5| for one |Nf6|
% \\
Position after \n f6-d7, white exchanged \B g6 for the \n f6
\end{center}
\bigskip

In Diagram XXX the plan for white is to maximally use the combined action of |Qf3| with the remained pieces.
Possible targets are via |Qf3-a8|, |Qf3-h3-e6|, |Qg3-g7|.

|Qc7| is a strong attacking and devensive ressource for black. Combined with |Ra8-b8| or |Nd7-c5|\dots

\q c7 is a strong attacking and devensive ressource for black. Combined with \r a8-b8 or \n d7-c5\dots

\bigskip

From Diagram XXX there are the following lines:

Line A, pawn sac: |13.f5 Bxg5+ 14.Kb1 Ne5 15.Kb1|

Line A, pawn sac: \verb:13.f5 Bxg5+ 14.Kb1 Ne5 15.Kb1:

Line A, pawn sac: \verb:|13.f5 Bxg5+ 14.Kb1 Ne5 15.Kb1|:

\end{document}
```

---

When running pdflatex on the above code, the following messages are shown by the latex compiler:

```
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LSF/berlin/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `LSF/skaknew/m/n' instead on input line 27.
```

---

The picture illustrates many glitches that i still have to solve somehow. This question addresses only one of them, how to get the right font, and thus have an available bl(ack) fontshape with it:

[image: Tex SE question on the berlin font]

---

---

---

*Note:* The code compiles with errors, after the first one i typed an `r` to run till the end. What i really finally want, is to have a way to type moves and chess specific symbols in a simple manner. This should happen without the constraint of always being in a mainline, or in a variation. So if the plan is Qc7-Qb6, Rb8, b5, and Q targets now b2, then something like

`|Qc7-Qb6, Rb8, b5|, and |Q| targets now |b2|`

is what i would like to type. This was the case - i think - in 2005, as i imported `chess`, and there was no mainline connected to the pipe symbols. (Now the latex code of all those days does no longer work, babel stays also in the way.) There is a big difference between what an author wants, and what she or he has now, now i have to type `\q c7-b6, \r b8, b5, and \q{} targets now b2`. Also, a chess specific format (like boldface, or spaces around the move numbers) is no longer captured.

---

---

**LATER EDIT:** Yes, the full solution of [Willie Wong](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/119/willie-wong) worked beautifully out of the box. To show the striking difference, and why i was so interested in a good font with black figurines, here is a sample usage of the `berlin` font, a nostalgic, but beautiful memento of the older translation books (from Russian originals) in the Sportverlag Berlin:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{chessfss,chessboard,xskak,texmate}
\usesymfig
\setchessfontfamily{berlin}

\renewcommand\P{\pawn}
  \newcommand\N{\knight}
  \newcommand\B{\bishop}
  \newcommand\R{\rook}
  \newcommand\Q{\queen}
  \newcommand\K{\king}

  \newcommand\p{{\fontshape{bl}\selectfont \textsymfigsymbol{p}}}
  \newcommand\n{{\fontshape{bl}\selectfont \textsymfigsymbol{n}}}
\renewcommand\b{{\fontshape{bl}\selectfont \textsymfigsymbol{b}}}
\renewcommand\r{{\fontshape{bl}\selectfont \textsymfigsymbol{r}}}
  \newcommand\q{{\fontshape{bl}\selectfont \textsymfigsymbol{q}}}
\renewcommand\k{{\fontshape{bl}\selectfont \textsymfigsymbol{k}}}

\parindent0pt
\advance\textwidth by 4cm
\advance\oddsidemargin by -2cm
\begin{document}
\sf\small
We switch to the \verb+\sl\large+ setting:
{\sl\large\par
White pieces: \P\N\B\R\Q\K\par
Black pieces: \p\n\b\r\q\k}

\bigskip

We are now back in the the \verb+\sf\small+ setting:\par
White pieces: \P\N\B\R\Q\K\par
Black pieces: \p\n\b\r\q\k

\bigskip

\begin{center}
Diagram XXX
\\
\newchessgame[moveid=13w,id=001]
\chessboard[smallboard
, setfen=r1b1k2r/2qnbppp/p2pp3/1p4P1/3NPP2/2N2Q2/PPP4P/2KR1B1R w kq - 1 13]
\\
{\bfseries B99:}
Position after \n f6-d7, white exchanged \B g5 for the \n f6
\end{center}
\bigskip

In Diagram XXX the plan for white is to maximally use the combined action
of \Q f3 with the remained pieces.\par
$\square$ possible targets are attacked via \Q f3-a8, \Q f3-h3-e6, \Q g3-g7.

\q c7 is a strong attacking and devensive ressource.
Combined with \r a8-b8 or \n d7-c5\dots

\bigskip

From Diagram XXX there are the following lines:

Line A, pawn sac, keeping initiative:
\variation{13.f5 Bxg5+ 14.Kb1 Ne5 15.Kb1}\par
Setting for black: \b g5, \n e5, \q d8 (but not \q e7, defending \p e6).\par
Note that \Q h5! wins back \p e6.\par
$\blacksquare$ counterplay on the f-file.\par
$\square$ controls, often occupies d5 via \N c3-d5, and the h-file.

\bigskip

Line B, slow improvement:
\variation{13.a3 Rb8 14.h4 b4 15.axb4 Rxb4 16.Bh3 Qc5! 17.Nb3 Qb6}\par
There are different nuances and ideas for each of the other earlier possible \q-moves):\par
16\dots\q b8? - allows \N c6 hitting \q b8, \r b4.\par
16\dots\q b7?! - allows 17.\B h3\takes e6 \p f7\takes e6 18.\N d4\takes e6-g7+ and \k often ends on \k d8.
Here, \p d6 is pinned, so white wins a tempo with \Q e3, \q b7 does not defend \n c5.\par
16\dots\q b6 - allows \N f5-\N g7+ in some variations, \P b2 for \p g7, both \K c1, \k e8 are exposed,
however \K c1 is slightly safer, all black pieces rather converge on the b-file.
\end{document}
```

And the result comes in supple format:

[image: tex stackexchange page view after having the solution]

Comment: sorry but your question is too long. Can't you simply say what the problem is instead of writing a long story about the background?

Comment: Huh, so, your question is about how to select the chess font? Or is it about how to create the syntax? It is a bit difficult to find the question ... maybe you can add a "tl;dr"?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The font is not recognized, this is the problem.

Comment: @JasperHabicht The Berlin font is not recognized by the code around the places marked in red. I would like to make this work. (There will be follow up questions... in any case posted separatedly.)

Comment: The initial post is edited, so that the question is explicitly stated. It is about the problem that may exist on the linux box that i am using now. Yes, i know, this is a Q&A-site, and the questions should go straightforward to the essence. But this also hides many problems behind the problems. Having one place for all chess authors using LaTeX may be also profitable for the community. In my case, many, very many ways to use the specific chess packages came from "secondary" aspects in questions around.

Comment: What is the `berlin` font? I have a complete TL installed and I cannot find any such font in the encoding you're requesting. You can't use an arbitrary chess font this way. It needs to be setup for LaTeX. Also, do *not* ask this on Arch's forums. If you need to, ask on Arco's. Arch's forums only allow questions about Arch and you're not using Arch.

Comment: I am pretty sure the `berlin` font is not packaged in either TL or in arch. It appears as part of the [enpassant package](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/chess/enpassant), which would need to be installed manually. The manual of [chessfss](https://ctan.org/pkg/chessfss) tells you how to do so (section 10 and 11). (Since you are after Berlin, you are lucky that the `pfb` files are included; some of the other fonts would require you to track down original TrueType fonts yourself and do the conversion...)

Comment: @cfr There are not too many chess fonts that provide also black chess figurines. This font is mentioned for instance in the pdf doc file for the package chessfss due to Ulrike Fischer, excellent work. For instance https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/chessfss/chessfss.pdf page 39 . There is also an `alpha` font, that seems to have the same properties. The AUR packager for chess-merida (Auguste) declares the source to be https://www.enpassant.dk/chess/downl/merid_tt.zip - which is some font providing also black figurines. (The latex name of this font would be useful...)

Comment: @dan_fulea: isn't the Merida font the one mentioned on page 46 of the chessfss manual?

Comment: @WillieWong Yes, it is that merida font, however, replacing berlin by merida in my sample code still delivers `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LSB/merida/m/n' undefined`. My great hope was that there would be some arch scheme that automatically does the job. This is a rolling distro, and relatively often texlive is touched. Then i have to remember to also update all AUR packages i am using. A manual install would mean for me to also write the script that does the job, add it to the procedure. I will finally install manually to see that the font works. In 2005 i was so far to write own mf code.

Comment: @dan_fulea That's an exaggeration of what's required. Although I'm using Arch, I've never used their TL packages. But assuming there's a `TEXMFLOCAL` (and, even if there isn't, Arch should let you make one - it's not Debian), you can install systemwide there without having to redo it when the TL packages are updated. However, like I say, I don't know how the packages are configured - only enough to create a dummy to convince `pacman` they're installed.

Comment: @cfr: since `enpassant` isn't in TL, I don't think you need to even fake it for `pacman`. // As to why it is not in TL, I have no idea; we'll have to wait for Ulrike. All I know is that tlmgr has no idea about that package or anything in it (which is as expected since on CTAN it is filed under `/tex-archive/`).

Comment: @WillieWong It doesn't meet the inclusion criteria for TL because the fonts aren't free, even though the support is LPPL. I fake `texlive` packages for `pacman`. So I can't check how Arch configures TL even though I'm on Arch. If I was installing `enpassant`, I'd install into `TEXMFLOCAL`. Once done, it stays done. But I don't know what's in Arch's `texmf.cnf`. (Though I will have to find out now.)

Comment: @dan_fulea the `chess-merida` AUR [does nothing more than](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=chess-merida) download the true-type Merida font and plops it somewhere on your system. If you are using XeLaTeX you may have a chance of using it directly. But in the present case, you still need to follow the instructions from chessfss manual to convert the TTF files for use in good old pdftex.

Comment: @dan_fulea Install `enpassant` into `/usr/local/share/texmf`, update the database and either run `updmap` in system mode or remember to add the map file fragment you need to your preamble. Unless Arch changes the framework, you shouldn't need to redo this and `pacman` won't touch `/usr/local/`. There doesn't seem to be a non-flat `enpassant`, so you'll need to make sure the various files end up in the correct directories. But they should stay put once there ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you've been installing stuff from AUR, I've made a PKGBUILD file that you can just use here.

1. Create a new directory somewhere.
2. In the directory, create a file named `PKGBUILD` with the following contents

```
pkgname=tex-enpassant
pkgver=1.1
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc='Enpassant chess fonts for diagrams and figurine notation'
arch=(any)
url='https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/chess/enpassant'
license=('custom')
source=('https://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/chess/enpassant.zip')
md5sums=('5d047d1c83416882b558226ce1c0fa53')
sha1sums=('0bd6240e4431a1f5cee7a11798f8e2ed315be9fa')
sha256sums=('4e921b822f46793eeea19729feb8596b4137a123a5e0c7c0e5ce5ada3dda58a9')

package() {
        cd $srcdir
        install -m644 -D -t "$pkgdir"/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/chess/enpassant enpassant/*.tfm
        install -m644 -D -t "$pkgdir"/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/chess/enpassant enpassant/*.pfb
        install -m644 -D -t "$pkgdir"/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/afm/chess/enpassant enpassant/*.afm
        install -m644 -D -t "$pkgdir"/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/chess/enpassant enpassant/*.enc
        install -m644 -D -t "$pkgdir"/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chessfss/enpassant enpassant/*.fd
        install -m644 -D -t "$pkgdir"/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/map/chess/enpassant enpassant/chess-enpassant.map
        cd ..
        install -m644 -D -t "$pkgdir"/var/lib/texmf/arch/installedpkgs/ $pkgname.maps
}
```

3. In the directory, create a file named `tex-enpassant.maps` with the following contents

```
Map chess-enpassant.map
```

4. In the directory, run `makepkg`.
5. If no errors, run `makepkg -si`

**Remark**. This is only minimally tested. (I checked that the package built fine, and that files made it to the right place, and that they got properly removed when I ran `pacman -R`. But I didn't check by compiling any docs.) And I didn't bother with dealing with fonts which Ulrike only provided the metrics for. (If you need them, feel free to edit the `PKGBUILD`.)

Comment: Re. the guidelines, I was mostly thinking of the preference for hooks rather than scripts and things like dependencies. I don't think you need the install script at all. The packaged TL installs pacman hooks which should run this stuff automatically. If you include the install script, you're just running stuff again. (https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/packaging/packages/texlive-texmf) I take it the idea is the same as the hooks for fonts: you don't use install scripts because otherwise `pacman` duplicates updates of the font databases for every font installed or removed.

Comment: Apparently, you can use `namcap` to check for 'common packaging errors' ;). You're obviously right about the double update. I think it is probably typically unnecessary (because I think I know why it might be), but for an unknown system, you'd have to do it to be sure. I've deleted that comment accordingly. I'm curious why they use `--force`.

Comment: @cfr: thank you for your help! That was extremely helpful. I've fixed the issue with hooks; now it is relying on the texmf hooks to update the TL and fonts databases.

Comment: BTW, please leave your two comments up; I think they would be useful, at least for future me.

Comment: Nice ;). (Can't upvote again.) You should also quote `$pkgdir` because it might have spaces or whatever.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that... when I wrote the last line. But somehow not the first 6 times. Fixed.

Comment: @WillieWong This answer is **highly** appreciated! Unfortunately i have only two clicks available... Now there's a quick receipt to apply the same in similar situations.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the help! All above comments are valuable (for me at any rate), and i may often come back here!

Comment: @dan_fulea It's better to look at the packaging guidelines and start from one of the provided templates. The guidelines change over time and as new features become available. E.g. before the hooks, every font package had to have an installation script (and installing several fonts at once was slow). Again, which directories to use has changed. `systemd` has changed things. Etc. Also, a recipe should include dependencies etc. If I used Arch's packages, I'd try this, though. But it's not enough to tempt me away from vanilla ;).